Is there any reason we can't use `df.sort(col('a').over('b'))` and instead `df.select(pl.all().sort_by('a').over('b'))`?
The first option seems way more straightforward to me, but it just sorts the whole dataframe according to a, without any windowing context. I looked in the issues but didn't find any discussion about this, except through the SQL API. Does anyone have any insights?

You can do df.sort('b', 'a').

Windows in this case are used to speed up computation by specifying that you only care that a is sorted with respect to b. df.sort('b', 'a') would take more resources

Makes sense! You might get a more insightful response by asking on the GitHub discussion tab of the polars repository.

If you do df.with_columns(key = col('a').over('b')) the .over() is essentially a no-op, right? df.sort(expr) is syntax sugar for pl.all().sort_by(expr) so it doesn't seem possible to express it via the shorthand version.

Ohh nvm I see now what you mean. pl.all().sort_by(col('a').over('b')) is different to pl.all().sort_by(col('a')).over('b')
